# I want to pull data from intranet ERP System what steps should i need to take using acumatica rest-api?

Tags: acumatica

I am developing an application and I want to pull Acumatica ERP data by using acumatica rest API. I installed acumatica configuration wizard to my local machine and deployed an application named "MyStoreInstance" using acumatica configuration wizard and then I am able to pull data by using postman

Url :  http://localhost/MyStoreInstance/OData/Customer%20Contacts

same thing I want to implement with clients ERP System. But Their ERP Systems are not available on the cloud so what process should I need to do with acumatica to pull data as I did locally. Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call into an external system you have 2 options:

1. Expose the system to the internet with DNS server. That means you host Acumatica on a public domain name and you call the API on that URL, ex:
   https://www.mycompany.com/MyStoreInstance/OData/Customer%20Contacts
2. Run the API client and API web service on the same local machine or the same private network. You could set up a secured encrypted VPN tunnel between your API client and the external web server. In that scenario you would call into the server similarly to how you call into localhost.

So you would need to ask the clients to host their system on the internet using a public domain name or ask them to provide you with some type of private network access (typically VPN).